# Mixing plus and space in tag delimiters

Tags: bug, status-norepro

An image is worth thousand words:

http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/7434/screenshot6iq.png

For the URL:

http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/557/screenshot5w.png

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged+php+or+c+++or+python+or+yii+or+c
```

Could you give me 9 more rep points, so I can post images and more than one link as well? It's the second bug I'm reporting today :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your URL is incorrect, FYI.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php or c%2b%2b or python or yii or c
```

That's what you want. Not escaping that plus is a recipe for pain.

Also, we have STRICT rules about mixing plus and space. **If any of your tags has a plus, you *MUST* use spaces to delimit.** Sorry, but that's the way the cookie crumbles when we allow tags with a plus in them.

So in short, you are doing this 99% wrong.

Also, I don't know how you arrived at a page that has "PHP, blah, blah, or blah Questions" in the tab-title. Which of our pages do that?

Comment: I think he's trying a little *too* hard to find bugs.

Comment: probably by using an unsupported browser :)