# Bug with tags with plus in name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, hyperlinks, url-encoding

https://stackoverflow.com/tools/ shows that a tag named [n+1](/questions/tagged/n%2b1) was created in the last 2 days. Clicking on [the link for that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n%2b1) takes one to a page showing "0 Questions tagged [n](/questions/tagged/n) [1](/questions/tagged/1)"; it treats them as two separate tags, despite the `+` being encoded as `%2b` in the URL.

Comment: Very interestingly, [the tag pages fetch the correct tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/n%2b1/faq) *despite* also rendering it as [n] [1] in the sidebar, and you can switch tabs and it'll retain it properly. This is also currently the only way you'll be able to easily find [the question with that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889479/how-to-avoid-n-1-with-datamapper-aggregates), due to the search oddities elaborated in this report. Normally, you can't even view these pages if you supply multiple tags.

Comment: This has [come up again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986837/i-m-new-to-rubycucumber-plz-help-me-out). The tag says `ruby+cucumber`, but it's immediately expanded to `[ruby][cucumber]` when clicking on it.

Comment: There are many tags on SO with + in them including [c++] and [c++-amp]. What is different about the "buggy" tags that makes them behave differently from these long-established tags?

Comment: @Kate only "++" are treated properly, e.g. [tag:n++1] is not splitted like [tag:n+1]. Guess the dev team put hard coded exception for "++" but not just for single "+".

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly hard-coded, but rather a switch on how we should split the path into an array of tags.  They can either be split by `%20` or by `+`.  The '+' character is tricky because there is no definitive standard for encoding spaces, and they can be encoded either as `+` or as `%20`.  Because URL-encoding is an important part of XSS defense, it makes it tricky to know when to encode a space as `%20` or as `+`, and even worse, whether when looking at a `+` if it was an encoded space or if it is an unencoded `+`.  The only way to deal with it is to try and construct general categories of use and deal with edge cases as they arise.

**Update**

Sorry for the delay here.  I got busy on other projects and some of the bugs I grabbed got put on the back burner.  Anyway, I may have spoken too soon.  Generally speaking, tags with the `+` character [are not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45353/how-can-i-create-a-tag-that-contains#comment123729_45656).  There are notable exceptions ([c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) being an obvious one), and those are the ones we work around.  This isn't one of those.  In fact, I don't think this tag ever got created.  There's no history for it at all.  In the case that a user really *must* have a `+` in the tag, the recommended workaround is to use 'plus' instead.  So if there are questions about some technology called Hellfire+Love and that's how everyone searches for it, then the tag would need to be `hellfire-plus-love`.

Also, for searching posts over tags, the rule is that [if *any* tag in the search has a `+` in it, you must use a space as a delimiter.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31179/mixing-plus-and-space-in-tag-delimiters)  See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47191/136973

Comment: I'm sorry, but [this is just wrong on so many levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20). There _is_ a "[definitive standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) for [encoding spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)", and if you find it "tricky" to tell encoded spaces and plus signs apart, that just means there's a bug (or several) in your code (or possibly in your design).

Comment: Ps. A possible source of confusion is that the rules are (slightly) different in the _path_ and _query_ parts of the URL: in the path, a literal `+` is just a plus sign, in the query it encodes a space. Fortunately, this is the _only_ difference -- in particular, `%20` always means a space, and `%2B` always means a plus sign. As long as your URL-encoding code always encodes spaces and plus signs as `%20` and `%2B` respectively, it will work for all parts of URLs.