# Plus sign in tags

Tags: bug, tags, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug with tags with plus in name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/bug-with-tags-with-plus-in-name)

Somehow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986837/i-m-new-to-rubycucumber-plz-help-me-out) has a tag `ruby+cucumber` (at least before it was edited). However, this tag appears to be impossible: selecting it immediately expands it into a conjunction of two separate tags, `[ruby][cucumber]`.

What is the nature of plus signs in tags? Are they allowed? Is this a bug?

Comment: It seems to be allowed in the list of tag, and in the question editor, but it will auto expand when click. Most likely a bug. You can tag the question with `ruby+cucumber` by using \ before `+`.

Comment: @TartLevee: Yes, I saw the duplicate, but I didn't know a way to bump it up -- just leaving a comment didn't seem to do the trick. Do feel free to close this if the duplicate gets addressed.