# C++ tag becomes C tag in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Tapping on tags like [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) removes `++` from search criteria.
Also I can't select right questions via **tag** menu. Results show [c] tagged questions, not [c++]. Old version of app did it well.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Related (site not app): [Bug with tags with plus in name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77757/307988)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

Following what web does, a single + will be treated as a separator (e.g., `/questions/tagged/php+javascript`) but multiple consecutive +'s won't (e.g., `/questions/tagged/c++`).

Comment: Can you say when new version will be released?

Comment: I'm planning to release it sometime next week.

Comment: What if I want to search for c++ plus php?

Comment: You can still search for `[c++][php]` as always.  The problem the app was facing was that we turned a tag into a link and then incorrectly parsed the link.  If Stack Overflow ever generates a link for two tagged questions, it can and does now use %20 as a divider, so `/questions/tagged/c++%20php` work on the site and in the app.